# Adding item to Contextual menu and send highlighted text to other app on MacOS

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to add a item to the global contextual menu in MacOS. Not by the user but by the app I'm writing.

Here's the scenario:

1. User installs my app, which should add the item to contextual menu.
2. When in another program the user highlights some text and "right clicks"/brings up contextual menu where the item added by my application should be shown.

Anyone know how to do this? 
I can't seem to find any documentation on how to add a item to the global contextual menu in macos without the user adding it as a service them selfs. I wan't this to be done when installing the app.

Comment: I'm trying to find out how to go about doing this. I havn't tried it since i don't know how to do it.

Comment: but i do not have any code since i don't know how where to start with this. I'm just trying to get in the right direction to see if anyone knows how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing is known as a "Service". The facility in general is sometimes known as Cocoa Services. See the [Services Implementation Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html) for details on how to have your app provide a service.

Comment: That's as far as i've gotten. But i don't know and can't find if a service can be added to contextual menu automatically somehow.

Comment: The OS takes care of that. Your app would advertise the service and what data types it handles. When another app brings up the contextual menu or the Services submenu of the application menu, the system asks it what kind of data it can provide (from its selection, usually) and shows the services which can handle that kind of data. So, yes, your service would be in the contextual menu whenever it's applicable.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to create a **share extension**.

You could read about extensions [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/) and specifically about share extension [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html).

Comment: Thanks but the other answer with services was more what i was looking for