# Get text from current cursor position From Pages app in Mac

Tags: macos, cocoa, applescript, accessibility

Is it possible to get the text of Pages app, from its current cursor position?
My requirement is like, when user type something in "Pages", I have to show suggestions for the word they are typing.

so I want to find out the current or last word, near current cursor position from "Pages" app.
Either by using AppleScript or Accessibility? 
Text is not selected.
I am not looking for "Services" also. 
For apps other than "Pages", I used Accessibility and appleScript. but for pages I am not finding any way.

I have also tried below AppleScript, but some reason it works perfectly in  "Script Editor", but when I use it in my code, it goes to infinite loop.

```
tell application "Pages"
    activate
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 123 using {shift down, command down} -- shift-command-left
    end tell
    tell process "Pages"
        keystroke "c" using {command down}
        delay 1
        tell application "System Events"
            key code 124 -- shift-command-left
        end tell
        set myData to (the clipboard) as text
        return myData
    end tell
end tell
```

If I run this AppleScript in my app, it freeze my Mac only, I have to force quit the Mac to stop it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding item to Contextual menu and send highlighted text to other app on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41484162/adding-item-to-contextual-menu-and-send-highlighted-text-to-other-app-on-macos)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically catch selected text in other application from my MacOSX application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52845062/programmatically-catch-selected-text-in-other-application-from-my-macosx-applica)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get global screen coordinates of currently selected text via Accessibility APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544311/how-to-get-global-screen-coordinates-of-currently-selected-text-via-accessibilit)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get currently selected text in active application in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980020/get-currently-selected-text-in-active-application-in-cocoa)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to obtain the selected text from another application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487175/how-to-obtain-the-selected-text-from-another-application)

Comment: @Willeke, thanks for links, but I am not asking for selected text. I want text which is before the caret position. if there is selection, I am able to get the text using Accessibility for some apps and for others I can use appleScript. But I want the text which is not selected, in Pages application. just by finding cursor position I want to get the text which is before that cursor/caret is placed. For the apps like Notes/Textedit, I got cursor position (even if there is no selection) by getting NSRange, and then I took text from 0 to the NSRange location I got.

Comment: Note: the linked questions are possible duplicates of the original question.

Comment: How do you execute the AppleScript in code? Are Xcode and/or your app allowed to control your computer?

Comment: @Willeke, using NSAppleScript. and yes my app is not sandbox so, app is allowed.

Comment: I tried `NSAppleScript` and the script and it runs ok (after solving the privacy issues).

Comment: The insertion point (text cursor) is just a zero-length selection. So, the links for getting the selection are relevant.

Comment: @Willeke, what privacy issues did you face?

Comment: @KenThomases, yes, links have solutions for getting zero-length selection, but does accessibility work with pages app? I am already using accessibility and zero length selection for apps like Notes & text editor, but for pages I am not getting any selection range.

Comment: Hmm, good point. The Accessibility Inspector doesn't show any elements within the scroll area of the document window. That's odd. I would have expected better accessibility support from an Apple app. For a different approach, can your task be achieved by implementing an input method? Those have a degree of access to the document into which you're typing.

Comment: @KenThomases, sorry, I didn't get what you mean by "For a different approach, can your task be achieved by implementing an input method? Those have a degree of access to the document into which you're typing."

Comment: `executeAndReturnError` returns an error "Not authorized to send Apple events".

Comment: There is one app "ViTre", which has same feature, while typing it shows suggestions. that app is showing suggestions for "Pages" app too. Even after I deny Accessibility permission for that app, it shows suggestions , that means they have used some other way.

Comment: I was suggesting that rather than an app (or perhaps in addition to an app), you implement an input method to achieve the ability to provide the suggestions UI you want.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me using the latest versions of macOS Mojave and Pages

```
property theApp : "Pages" -- change value to name of any other application (TextEdit)

tell application theApp to activate
delay 3
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process theApp
        -- Move the insertion point to the beginning of the previous word.
        key code 123 using {option down} -- left arrow key while holding option down
        delay 0.2
        -- Move the insertion point to the end of the next word. (selects the word)
        key code 124 using {shift down, option down} -- right arrow key while holding option and shift down
        delay 0.2
        keystroke "c" using {command down} -- copies selected wprd 
        delay 0.2
        -- Next 2 key code commands attempt to restore cursor location  
        key code 124 using {option down} -- right arrow key while holding option down
        delay 0.2
        key code 123 using {option down} -- left arrow key while holding option down
        tell current application to set myData to (the clipboard) as text
        delay 4
        return myData
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: I am still facing same issue. when I run this AppleScript in my project it goes to infinite loop and freeze the Mac, I have to force shut down to stop it. I am calling this appleScript on NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents, so that when user type something I will get the last words from cursor position.

Comment: @KrishnaMaru it would help us to help you if you provide this information in the question. Your monitor block is triggered by the keystrokes from the AppleScript.

Comment: @KrishnaMaru updated the code in my post.  Does the new version work any better for you?

Comment: @wch1zpink, found the issue. I am calling this AppleScript on NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown), so first time it will run the appleScript, but again in our appleScript we have 124/123 keyDown event, which will make this AppleScript to run in infinite loop.